# How to confirm (not verify) an email address with devise in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise and I'm trying to add an email_confirmation input, I want my users to type their email address twice in order to make sure that they didn't make any mistake (like the password_confirmation input). I have searched for a solution for days but all I can find is how to "verify" an email address. How would the validation work ? Any answer/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm their email address, add the field `email_confirmation` to the form:

run `rails generate devise:views` so that devise views are available within the application.

add `email_confirmation` to the devise form.

Then allow this parameter to be passed to devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

The last step is to add the validation to `User` model (or the model you use with devise):
`validates :email, confirmation: true`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a regular expression validation. Something like this should do the trick:

```
validates :email,
format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, message: 'Invalid email' }
```

That's assuming that by "verify" you mean simply "check that the thing the user entered looks like a valid email".

There's an additional step of verification, not taken by most apps, which checks that the email not only looks like a valid email, but actually *is* an email address that exists in real life. If that's what you're after, check out https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that my question wasn't very clear. I want my users to type their email address twice in order to make sure that they didn't make any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.